# Loop until variable != ""

Tags: batch-file, while-loop, adb, dos

I want to make a batch file that sends certain values to a output.txt. I have the following code:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb logcat -v threadtime | grep -m 1 'VAC: App Name is:'') do set appName=%%a

echo App Name= %appName% > output.txt
```

The problem is that the grep statement doesn't immediately return a value--not until a user performs a certain action on the Android device. So I need to create a loop around the "for" statement. I'll make an attempt below, but I know it's wrong.

```
do
while 
%appName% = ""
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb logcat -v threadtime | grep -m 1 'VAC: App Name is:'') do set appName=%%a

    if "%appName% != "" leave
enddo

echo App Name= %appName% > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set "appName="
:loop
for /F "delims=" %%a in (
    'adb logcat -v threadtime ^| grep -m 1 "VAC: App Name is:"'
) do set "appName=%%a"
if not defined appName goto loop
```

It just clears the variable and keep looping until it gets any value in it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (although MC ND's answers looks good too):
Please note pipe needs to be escaped by caret`^`, I added a 1 secs wait `ping -n 1 -w 1000 1.1.1.1 >nul`

```
:while_loop
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`adb logcat -v threadtime ^| grep -m 1 'VAC: App Name is:'`) do set appName=%%a
ping -n 1 -w 1000 1.1.1.1 >nul
if not "%appName% == "" goto exit_loop
goto while_loop


:exit_loop
echo App Name= %appName% > output.txt
```